# Error: Could not find or load main class Swagger Codegen

Tags: java, jar, swagger-codegen

I left an open issue for [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3339)

---

I´m trying to create a custom codegen, I managed to make it work by putting the files inside of the codegen project but I want it to work like this: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#making-your-own-codegen-modules

I haven't modified the autogenerated project at all but I keep getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen
```

This is the command line:

```
java -cp output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation
```

I got the jar from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-codegen-project/2.1.6
This is what I'm doing:

1. Run  `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar meta \ -o output/myLibrary -n myClientCodegen -p com.my.company.codegen`  to create costume codegen
2. Run `mvn package` in output/myLibrary
3. Run `java -cp output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation` in the folder that contains both swagger-codege-cli-2.1.6.jar and the output folder

It does find the class if I remove the first part, but doesn´t find the new language:

```
java -cp swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation
```

I have looked at the answers for "Error: Could not find or load main class" problems but haven't manage to fix it.

[Here is a link to the jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4p45mjTMTnLWVlPVTBGdXVLX0k/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't specify that correct path of `swagger-codegen-2.1.6.jar` in your call. Thats why it can't find the `main`-class.

If you are inside the root project `swagger-codegen` you should specify it like this: `modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar`

```sh
~$ cd ~/git/swagger-codegen # go into your root project
~/git/swagger-codegen$ # ... do the steps you described
~/git/swagger-codegen$ java  -cp \
 output/myLibrary/target/myClientCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
 io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen \
 generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json \
 -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator \
 -o outputlocation
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
~/git/swagger-codegen$ java  -cp output/myLibrary/target/myClientCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation
```

**Update 1**

I'm pretty sure when you construct the classpath with `-cp` you have a mistake with the `swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar`. Please test the following.

Copy both (`myClientCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar` and `swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar`) jars into the same folder. Then go into this folder and try the following:

```
javap -cp myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen
```

java**p** checks whether the main class `io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen` is available. On my machine it prints this:

```
Compiled from "SwaggerCodegen.java"
public class io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen {
  public io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not in the root project swagger-codegen, as I said this: `java -cp swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation` works just fine, which means it's able to find the class as long as I don't include the path for `myClientCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar`

Comment: that means you have `swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar` in your current directory. Are you sure about that? The exception u mentioned you get if java doesn't have access to the `swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar`. I'm pretty sure it is related to that. The wicked thing is that java doesn't log an error if it can't finde the jar you mentioned.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. If I wanted I could use any of the languages already defined by swagger calling it like that. The problem only appears when adding the path to my jar.

Comment: can u upload your jar somewhere? I would try to place both in the same folder on my mac

Comment: just updated the question with a link to the jar, thanks

Comment: Can you try putting both jars in the same folder? then `cd` into this folder and try like this: `java -cp myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation` Maybe the slashes are a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117438/discussion-between-d0x-and-moondaisy).

Answer (score 3):

For Windows, change the colon (`:`) to a semicolon (`;`) - between the jars in the class path.  So instead of

```
java -cp output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar:swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation
```

It should be

```
java -cp output/myLibrary/target/myCustomCodegen-swagger-codegen-1.0.0.jar;swagger-codegen-cli-2.1.6.jar io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen generate -i https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/listings/conversation-v1-experimental.json -l com.my.company.codegen.Mycustomcodegengenerator -o outputlocation
```

Multiple class paths need to be separated by a semicolon.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Be careful, this is only correct if you use Windows. For `Solaris/Linux` it says: `% setenv CLASSPATH classpath1:classpath2...`. I assume (and might be wrong) that for `UNIX` it would be a `:` as well, not `;`

Comment: @chriszo111 why the downvote? The link included did indicate it was Windows specific, so it's still useful.

Comment: IMO a lot of people read over the answer, do not click the link only to find out, after they applied the solution, that it's not their problem. However, I edited the answer and removed my downvote, but I think the quality of the answer could have been better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @chriszo111! I imagine at the time (3 long years ago haha) I was just trying to help provide info. But I see your point of adding more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar problem when running as Spring Boot app in Eclipse 4.19 in macOS 10.14:

> "Error: Could not find or load main class
> io.swagger.Swagger2SpringBoot"

…even as I was staring at this very class containing the main method. My solution was issuing a "maven update project". This, like in other situations with odd Java symptoms, fixed the issue.